# How can I backup a SharePoint wiki and view it offline?

Tags: sharepoint, wiki

I am looking for a way to backup a SharePoint 2007 wiki and view it offline, if possible without using the central administration and stsadm. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get wiki data out of Sharepoint - at least not without admin access to the server or database.

**The best you can do is to create a new view** with the columns *Name* and *Wiki Content*, then copy&paste from your browser into Word.... yes, I know it sucks but we haven't found a better way either, and the corporate Sharepoint team can't offer anything better either.

It sounds like you're already invested in Sharepoint, but in case you're just starting out, **I'd like to suggest that you look at alternatives, too.**

The wiki functionality was probably thrown into Sharepoint for marketing reasons, so MS can say that they offer a wiki. But the Sharepoint wiki offers very poor functionality.
**I recommend using [Foswiki](http://foswiki.org) instead because of it's strong focus on corporate intranet use,** but [Wikimatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) can also reveal interesting alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I agree 100% with your statement regarding the quality of the wiki in SharePoint 2007.